# PHP fatal error when call mysqli_fetch_array

Tags: php, drupal, easyphp, drush

I am using Drush which is launching php in command line. I copied my initial php.ini in my local directory so that php is using the same configuration as if it was launched by the web server. When used with the web server, it works well. Unfortunately, when launched with the command line, PHP crashes when drush calls mysqli_fetch_array and/or mysqli_fetch_object while everything is fine when calling mysqli_fetch_row... I am using EasyPHP 5.2.10 under windows.

**Error message:** an unhandled win32 exception occurred in php.exe [5772]. Just-In_time debugging this exception failed with the following error: No installed debugger has Just-In_time debugging enabled. In Visual Studio, Just-In-Time debugging can be enabled from Tools/Options/Debugging/Just-In-Time.

As requested in the comments, here are the information about PHP and the MySQLi module. 
**Remark**: The Client API library version and the Cient API header version are different. However, they are the same when using the web server phpinfo()... Could this be the problem? It is however a fresh easyPHP install...Oo'.

**php -v**

PHP 5.2.10 (cli) (built: Jun 17 2009 16:16:57)
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies

**php -i**

phpinfo()
PHP Version => 5.2.10

System => Windows NT APOLLON 5.1 build 2600
Build Date => Jun 17 2009 16:16:01
Configure Command => cscript /nologo configure.js  "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-snapshot-template=d:\php-sdk\snap
_5_2\vc6\x86\template" "--with-php-build=d:\php-sdk\snap_5_2\vc6\x86\php_build" "--with-pdo-oci=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared
" "--with-oci8=D:\php-sdk\oracle\instantclient10\sdk,shared"
Server API => Command Line Interface
Virtual Directory Support => enabled
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => C:\WINDOWS
Loaded Configuration File => C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.2.10\www\drush\php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files => (none)
additional .ini files parsed => (none)
PHP API => 20041225
PHP Extension => 20060613
Zend Extension => 220060519
Debug Build => no
Thread Safety => enabled
Zend Memory Manager => enabled
IPv6 Support => enabled
Registered PHP Streams => php, file, data, http, ftp, compress.zlib
Registered Stream Socket Transports => tcp, udp
Registered Stream Filters => convert.iconv.*, string.rot13, string.toupper, string.tolower, string.strip_tags, convert.*, consumed, zlib.*

This program makes use of the Zend Scripting Language Engine:
Zend Engine v2.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies

---

Configuration

PHP Core

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
allow_call_time_pass_reference => Off => Off
allow_url_fopen => On => On
allow_url_include => Off => Off
always_populate_raw_post_data => Off => Off
arg_separator.input => & => &
arg_separator.output => & => &
asp_tags => Off => Off
auto_append_file => no value => no value
auto_globals_jit => On => On
auto_prepend_file => no value => no value
browscap => no value => no value
default_charset => no value => no value
default_mimetype => text/html => text/html
define_syslog_variables => Off => Off
disable_classes => no value => no value
disable_functions => no value => no value
display_errors => STDOUT => STDOUT
display_startup_errors => On => On
doc_root => no value => no value
docref_ext => no value => no value
docref_root => no value => no value
enable_dl => On => On
error_append_string => no value => no value
error_log => no value => no value
error_prepend_string => no value => no value
error_reporting => 6143 => 6143
expose_php => On => On
extension_dir => C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.2.10\php\ext\ => C:\Program Files\EasyPHP5.2.10\php\ext\
file_uploads => On => On
highlight.bg => #FFFFFF => #FFFFFF
highlight.comment => #FF8000 => #FF8000
highlight.default => #0000BB => #0000BB
highlight.html => #000000 => #000000
highlight.keyword => #007700 => #007700
highlight.string => #DD0000 => #DD0000
html_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_errors => Off => Off
ignore_repeated_source => Off => Off
ignore_user_abort => Off => Off
implicit_flush => On => On
include_path => .;C:\php5\pear => .;C:\php5\pear
log_errors => On => On
log_errors_max_len => 1024 => 1024
magic_quotes_gpc => Off => Off
magic_quotes_runtime => Off => Off
magic_quotes_sybase => Off => Off
mail.force_extra_parameters => no value => no value
max_execution_time => 0 => 0
max_input_nesting_level => 64 => 64
max_input_time => -1 => -1
memory_limit => 128M => 128M
open_basedir => no value => no value
output_buffering => 0 => 0
output_handler => no value => no value
post_max_size => 8M => 8M
precision => 14 => 14
realpath_cache_size => 16K => 16K
realpath_cache_ttl => 120 => 120
register_argc_argv => On => On
register_globals => Off => Off
register_long_arrays => Off => Off
report_memleaks => On => On
report_zend_debug => Off => Off
safe_mode => Off => Off
safe_mode_exec_dir => no value => no value
safe_mode_gid => Off => Off
safe_mode_include_dir => no value => no value
sendmail_from => no value => no value
sendmail_path => no value => no value
serialize_precision => 100 => 100
short_open_tag => Off => Off
SMTP => localhost => localhost
smtp_port => 25 => 25
sql.safe_mode => Off => Off
track_errors => On => On
unserialize_callback_func => no value => no value
upload_max_filesize => 2M => 2M
upload_tmp_dir => ${path}\tmp\ => ${path}\tmp\
user_dir => no value => no value
variables_order => GPCS => GPCS
xmlrpc_error_number => 0 => 0
xmlrpc_errors => Off => Off
y2k_compliance => On => On
zend.ze1_compatibility_mode => Off => Off

[Skipped]

mysqli

MysqlI Support => enabled
Client API library version => 5.1.42
Client API header version => 5.0.51a
MYSQLI_SOCKET => /tmp/mysql.sock

Directive => Local Value => Master Value
mysqli.default_host => no value => no value
mysqli.default_port => 3306 => 3306
mysqli.default_pw => no value => no value
mysqli.default_socket => no value => no value
mysqli.default_user => no value => no value
mysqli.max_links => Unlimited => Unlimited
mysqli.reconnect => Off => Off

Any idea?

Regards.

Comment: Umm, what does the fatal error say? Copy, paste.

Comment: Edited post with fatal error message.

Comment: my friend, that "etc" is quite important. Please copy-paste the _entire_ error message.

Comment: Edited post to put the entire fatal error message while I don't think it adds any valuable information as it is the "standard" windows fatal error message...;-)

Comment: What happens when you call mysqli_fetch_array by "hand" using the commandline "php -a" and pasting in a piece of php with these function-calls? 
Also: providing some information on the version of php and compiled and used modules would be handy. php -i and php -v offer such information (note: that is a lot of information)

Comment: I can't call php -a as I am under Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my problem thanks to all your comments and answers that put me on the right track. The version of MyQSLi was ok when working with the web server but not with the command line. I noticed this when doing php -i as suggested. So, to correct this problem, you should **[download the files here](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/mods/PHP-5.2.9+_MySQL-5.1.30+.zip)** and **put them in your PHP \EXT directory** to replace the old ones.

Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Probably an extension compatibility problem.  Either the module was not compiled for your version of PHP or it's corrupt/missing.

I've seen this happen with other LAMP stacks when the command-line PHP interpreter isn't finding the correct extension directory.

Comment: Oh, I see. How could I find which module is not correct and how could I correct this issue then? Thanks for your help!